# What is the best way to avoid hyphenation of all acronyms defined with glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, hyphenation

Today the problem given is, that I want to prevent the hyphenation of all words defined with `\newacronym` for the `glossaries` package.

An example of a document that would have `HStA` break between S and t which is not desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[a6paper,textwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\newacronym[sort=HStA]{HStA}{HStA}{Hauptstaatsarchiv}

\begin{document}
\gls{HStA} is illustrating the problem.
Because with a long wooooooooooooooord \gls{HStA} will be broken with a hyphen.
\end{document}
```

The manual way of doing this would be:

```
\newacronym[sort=HStA]{HStA}{\mbox{HStA}}{Hauptstaatsarchiv}
```

The abbreviation can be accessed with `\gls{HStA}` and is typeset as `\mbox{HStA}`, so it stays in one line, because it is protected by an `\mbox`, no matter what.

But is there a way to automate this or tell glossaries by default to not allow breaking abbreviations?

Comment: a MWE would help but I assume that's German, in English at least lefthyphenmin and righthyphenmin mean that you need at least 5 letters before hyphenation is considered so Abt wouldn't need any special markup

Comment: but `\let\zzz\newacronym`, `\renewcommand\newacronym[3]{\zzz{#1}{\mbox{#2}}{#3}}` probably does what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I will provide a MWE tomorrow. Sorry for my sloppiness.

Comment: but the above (corrected) comment probably does what you want, even without a MWE:-)

Comment: This isn't automatic, but adding a`\hyphenation` list to your preamble (with these abbreviated forms including no hyphens) would suppress such hyphenations.  The rules for German should define `\lefthyphenmin` and `righthy[phenmin` so any shorter abbreviation shouldn't need to be listed.

Comment: This older question of mine appears to be quite similar. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370787/134144

Comment: @leandriis I like the solution `\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\mbox{#1}}` from the other question the most I guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for that hint and of course I am aware of that possibility with `babel`, but as you mention, it's not automatic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a MWE and with the optional argument, your solution must be enhanced again. However the solution given in the original of this duplicate is what I like most, so `\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\mbox{#1}}` ist the way I will go.