# How to prevent hyphenation of abbreviations when glossary has the choice to use the long form?

Tags: glossaries, hyphenation

I followed the advice given by @NicolaTalbot (by the way thanks for creating the great glossaries package!) in [hyphenation of abbreviation using the glossaries package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370787/hyphenation-of-abbreviation-using-the-glossaries-package) to avoid hyphenation of abbreviations.

However I have an example where the abbreviation still breaks, because if you use the `\gls` command and let `glossaries` select whether it should take the long form, or the short, the `\acronymfont` is not used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\newacronym[sort=BayHStA]{BayHStA}{BayHStA}{Bayerisches Hauptstaatsarchiv}

\begin{document}
    \gls{BayHStA} and this is to show us that \gls{BayHStA} can break, even though it has been put into a mbox.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A modified solution based on @Georg's idea however can be applied and leads to the expected behaviour:

```
\newcommand{\nonbreakableacronym}[4][]{\hyphenation{#3}\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\nonbreakableacronym[sort=BayHStA]{BayHStA}{BayHStA}{Bayerisches Hauptstaatsarchiv}
```

But I liked the neatness of Nicolas version, can something similar be achieved by just using another font command of `glossaries`?

---

**Addition**

There is an additional problem with the approach when you want to apply it. That is, that `\hyphenation` does not like words ending with a full stop. This is why:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\nonbreakableacronym}[4][]{\hyphenation{#3}\newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
%\nonbreakableacronym[sort=BayHStA]{BayHStA}{BayHStA}{Bayerisches Hauptstaatsarchiv}
\newacronym[sort=BayHStA]{BayHStA}{bayHStA}{Bayerisches Hauptstaatsarchiv}
\nonbreakableacronym[sort=Abt.]{Abt.}{Abt.}{Abteilung}

\begin{document}
    \gls{BayHStA} and this is to show us that \gls{BayHStA} can break, even though it has been put into a mbox. \Gls{BayHStA} works as well.
    
    But I cannot use \gls{Abt.} without getting an error, because of the full stop.
\end{document}
```

produces an error:

```
! Not a letter.
<argument> Abt.
               
l.9 ...leacronym[sort=Abt.]{Abt.}{Abt.}{Abteilung}
                                                  
Letters in \hyphenation words must have \lccode>0.
Proceed; I'll ignore the character I just read.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try with

```
\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\asillyundefinedmacro\mbox{#1}}
```

you will receive *no* error message about `\asillyundefinedmacro` being undefined.

You need to choose a style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\newacronym[sort=BayHStA]{BayHStA}{BayHStA}{Bayerisches Hauptstaatsarchiv}

\begin{document}

\gls{BayHStA} and this is to show us that \gls{BayHStA} can break, even though 
it has been put into a mbox.

\end{document}
```

Compile and you'll get an “overfull `\hbox`" warning and no break in the short form of the acronym.

Comment: Thanks egreg, what is happening when I do not set the `\acronymstyle`? I cannot find a reference in the manual for this.

Comment: @TobiBS Neither could I. I tried with that method, to realize that `\acronymfont` never got used.